# How do I extract the fourm link by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I found a link in the forum.

[image]

However, when I use this code below to find all the links in this page

```
url="https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/forums/type-1-diabetes.9/"
r1b=requests.get(url)
if r1b.status_code==200:
  print("Accessible.")
sp1b=BeautifulSoup(r1b.text,'lxml')
import re
for link in sp1b.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")}):
    # display the actual urls
    print(link.get('href'))
```

It don't give the hyperlink of the forums, could ask how could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source_html = requests.get("https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/forums/type-1-diabetes.9/")
links = [
    f'https://www.diabetesdaily.com{a["href"]}' for a
    in BeautifulSoup(source_html.content, "html.parser").select(".structItem-title a")
]
print("\n".join(links))
```

Output:

```
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/had-a-friend-with-type-one.136015/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/learning-center-type-1-diabetes.132494/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/anyone-use-a-pump-only-for-basal.141761/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/glucose-tablets.141716/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/i-was-just-informed-i-have-type-1.141674/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/sudden-highs.141453/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/edema-anyone-t1d.141499/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/help.141377/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/news-why-is-insulin-still-so-expensive-for-diabetes-patients-in-the-u-s.141131/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/professions.141633/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/metformin.141639/
https://www.diabetesdaily.com/forum/threads/are-dexcom-g6-and-ios-16-now-compatible.141617/
```